# Tengo este codigo que genera un csv conectado a una base de datos pero me lo genera en Unix LF y debo convertirlo a CRLF pero no se como hacerlo

Tags: php, csv

Simplemente al generar el csv luego al abrirlo se muestra en fomrato lf unix y no en crlf pero no se muy bien como realizarlo

```
 $floritura=date('YmdHis');
  $floritura2=date('ymdHi');
$salida_cvs = ""."";
$rara='R00';
$rara1='000000';
$delimiter=';';
foreach($dades as $barres){
    
    $codibarres[] = array('id' => $barres['id'],'codigo_barras' => $barres['codigo_barras'],
    'alto' => $barres['alto'], 'ancho' => $barres['ancho'],
    'profundidad' => $barres['profundidad'], 'peso'  => $barres['peso'], 'fecha' => $barres['fecha'], 'hora' => $barres['hora']);

    $salida_cvs .= "$rara"."$delimiter"."$floritura"."$delimiter".$barres['id']."$delimiter".$barres['peso']."$delimiter".$barres['alto']."$delimiter".$barres['ancho']."$delimiter".$barres['profundidad']."$delimiter".$rara1."$delimiter".$barres['codigo_barras']."$delimiter"."$floritura2"."$delimiter".$barres['id'];
    $salida_cvs .= "\n";
```

Aquí lo que hace es extraer la info de una consulta y guardarla dandole el fomrato que desea el cliente

```
Aquí genera el csv y demás
}
//file_put_contents("../csv_generados/codigo_cajas$suma.csv",$salida_cvs);
$fechaActual = date("d-m-Y");
file_put_contents("../csv_generados/my_csv_file.csv",$salida_cvs);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$fechaActual.csv"); 
define('CRLF', "\r\n");
readfile('my_csv_file.csv', true);
session_start();
?>
´´´
Explicando un poco el codigo este primero desde una busqueda gurda los datos y luego al descargar los archivos los extrae de la consulta luego genera un csv con el formato UNIX LF
```

Comment: Cuando generas el csv cambia ` $salida_cvs .= "\n";` por ` $salida_cvs .= "\r\n";`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ha funcionado